# Can't get desired result on Java program

Tags: java

the problem set asks me to create a bunch of methods in a class Debt.
The method printBalance prints the current balance, and the waitOneYear method grows the debt amount.

The debt is increased by multiplying the balance by the interest rate.

The program should output
120000.0 ,
121200.0 ,
147887.0328416936
after using this test code:

```
Debt mortgage = new Debt(120000.0, 1.01);
        mortgage.printBalance();

        mortgage.waitOneYear();
        mortgage.printBalance();

        int years = 0;

        while (years < 20) {
            mortgage.waitOneYear();
            years = years + 1;
        }

        mortgage.printBalance();
```

The code on my Debt class is:

```
    private double balance;
    private double interestRate;
    public Debt(double initialBalance, double initialInterestRate) {
        balance = initialBalance;
        interestRate = initialInterestRate;


    }
    public void printBalance(){
        System.out.println(balance);

    }
    public void waitOneYear(){
        this.balance = this.balance + (this.balance*(this.interestRate/100));

    }
```

I'm getting the first 2 integer values from test code correct, however my third value is coming out to be 148194.8253662062.
Can anyone help?

Comment: The third value that you want is the debt value after 20 years?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a floating point error. This is a good read on the topic https://dzone.com/articles/never-use-float-and-double-for-monetary-calculatio

This is why when dealing with currencies in Java you MUST always use BigDecimal

Here is your code converted to use BigDecimal.

```
static class Debt {
    private BigDecimal balance;
    private BigDecimal interestRate;


    Debt(double initialBalance, double initialInterestRate) {
        balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(initialBalance);
        interestRate = BigDecimal.valueOf(initialInterestRate);
    }

    public void printBalance() {
        System.out.println(balance.setScale(10, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));

    }

    public void waitOneYear() {
        this.balance = this.balance.add(this.balance.multiply(this.interestRate.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100), RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN)));

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Debt mortgage = new Debt(120000.0, 1.01);
    mortgage.printBalance();

    mortgage.waitOneYear();
    mortgage.printBalance();

    int years = 0;

    while (years < 20) {
        mortgage.waitOneYear();
        years = years + 1;
    }

    mortgage.printBalance();

}
```